# Table - Ant Design, onRow DoubleClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want open modal window, when i doubleClick onRow in Table antd. And pass property to modal. Like this:

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    components={components}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    onRow={(record) => {
        return {
            onDoubleClick: () => {
                return <ModalWindow props={record} />
                // or
                return <ModalWindow> {record.name} </ModalWindow>
            }
        }
    }} />
```

The problem is that no jsx is returned. I can save in state, like here:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
const [record, setRecord] = useState([]);  
<Table
        columns={columns}
        components={components}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        onRow={(record) => {
            return {
                onDoubleClick: () => {
                    setRecord(record);
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }} />
        {visible &&
            <ModalWindow record={record} />
        }
```

but that's not my way. Help me, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle your requirement by using one `Modal` and updating content of modal with double-click on every row, like this:

```
function App() {
  // ...
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [activeRecord, setActiveRecord] = useState(null);

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        onRow={(record) => {
          return {
            onDoubleClick: () => {
              setActiveRecord(record);
              setIsModalVisible(true);
            },
          };
        }}
      />
      <Modal
        title="User info"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onCancel={closeModal}
        footer={null}
      >
        {/* render whatever you want based on your record */}
        <p>{activeRecord?.name} </p>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've implemented an example [Here on stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twfrck), you can check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, Saeed. But tell me, pls, if you know, why onDoubleClick can't return JSX? Or maybe he can?

Comment: @100Pudof `onRow` uses to set props on every row, it should return an object and antd will pass the returned object to row component as some additional props

Comment: @100Pudof if my answer was helpful, i would appreciate to mark it as accepted.